# VBA - Delete Visible Rows After Filter Applied

Tags: vba, excel

I have the two Macro's which filters a worksheet column by date and then delete's the irrelevant columns.

However, it is very buggy and I need some help to correct that please.

This is what the second Macro is supposed to do:

1) **Simply delete the visible rows after the filter is applied, except the first row (headers)** - Currently, it deletes ALL visible rows including the first row, even though I have the `Offset` function in my code.

2) **Remove all filters** - This is working fine now

```
Sub DeleteVisibleRows()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim WorkRng As Range

Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Consolidated")

On Error Resume Next

Set WorkRng = Application.Selection

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ws1

WorkRng.Offset(1, 0).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

ws1.AutoFilterMode = False

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem lies in the line `Set WorkRng = Application.Selection`.  You should avoid using `Selection` and try to define your range better.  What is the `Selection` when this macro is run?  You can offset by 1, but still include the headers.  Also, the `On Error Resume Next` isn't necessary and not resetting it will prevent you from seeing other errors.

Comment: @DarrellH the selection is the filtered data from after the first macro is applied. So I filter out the date from the previous day, then the data that is displayed would become my selection. I see many people highly against on error resume next, im not a vba coder so i dont know why it is so. What can I do instead of that?

Comment: I see you have a lot of options now.  The reason against `On Error Resume Next` is that you cannot debug what you do not know.  There are cases where it is applicable, but you should know why.

Comment: @DarrellH Okay, thank you for the advice :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SpecialCells will work like the previous answer.

```
    Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, LstRw As Long

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
    With sh
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("A2:A" & LstRw).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        rng.EntireRow.Delete
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Deleting rows of filtered data is something I needed time to time while working with tables in excel, but I could never trust a macro when it comes to deleting important stuff. If you still want to use it, this might work for you:

```
Sub DeleteVisibleRows()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidated")
With ws
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1 'To 2 Assuming first row contains headers
        If .Rows(i).Hidden = False Then
            .Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next
.ShowAllData 'remove filtered data
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @EitelDagnin For example I forgot to add ws reference to my range which I edited now. Such mistakes might result in deleting data from incorrect/currently active sheets.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your code, unfortunately, the code gets stuck in a loop and I waited about 2-3 minutes before I actually cancelled the macro by force.

Comment: @EitelDagnin What is your table's range in "Consolidated" sheet? Are there any other entries after your table?

Comment: There isn't a "table" in the sheet. Its just raw data in the cells. I didn't create a table from the data.

Comment: @EitelDagnin Ok let me ask you this way: What is your filtered range including headers?

Comment: So I copy data from 3 sheets into the consolidated sheet, but the data is pasted from row 2 onward as in row one there are column headings. I filter the data (which will vary in length on each import) on column B which in row one has the heading Date. This filters the data by date and then I need to delete what is visible while the filter is applied. I hope that managed to answer your question?

Comment: @EitelDagnin I think you don't have any data on Column A. it might be the issue. I change the lastrow due to Column B since you mentioned you filter it. I also found a bug and tweaked the code. It was not deleting the adjacent values so I reversed the loop from bottom to top. Can you try now?

Comment: Thank you again for your reply, but the code just hangs. I have to force-stop the macro.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `SELECTION` there's no need to define the worksheet. Everything you need is relevant to your selection - your selection may not be on the `Consolidated` worksheet, it will always be on the parent object of your selection though.

The code below assumes you have a filter applied - if it isn't then everything below the heading gets deleted.

```
Public Sub DeleteVisibleRows()

    Dim WorkRng As Range

    Set WorkRng = Selection

    With WorkRng
        .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

    WorkRng.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

**Edit:**  That code's too long, I'll get rid of some of the junk.

```
Public Sub DeleteVisibleRows()

    With Selection
        .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I get a Application-Defined or Object-Defined error @Darren

Comment: That's odd.  I can't get it to _not_ work.  I tried putting the code behind `Sheet1` and selected a range in `Sheet2`, I tried putting the code in `Book2` and selecting a range in `Book1`.  Each time it deleted the visible rows in the selection, leaving the header.  So what's special about your data that could cause.... are your cells locked and the sheet protected anywhere on the rows you're trying to delete?  That would cause the error - when it can't delete the cells you're telling it to.

Comment: No, cells are not locked and there is no protection on the sheet or the workbook. I honestly do not know what to say here. I copied the code EXACTLY that was in your code block under the "Edit" in your question, and then ran the code and this is the error I get..

Comment: You only have one cell selected?  With only a single cell then `.Rows.Count` will return 1 and `?Selection.Resize(Selection.Rows.Count-1).Address` will return the error message (resizing the selection to 0 rows).

Comment: Thank you @Darren, its not a problem, Davesexcel provided a solution and its working great. Thank you for your help nevertheless :)