# delete Autofilter Field resullt using the header Name

Tags: vba, excel

I used the  Autofilter function but using field with the header name "ID" instead the number of column. for this part it's ok. Then I tried to delete the autofilter result but I'm Stuck. I saw that there is several questions about this  problematic but there is no a solution. however i tried this code but it doesn't work.

I will use this macro for several data. the purpose is to clean all data where there is blank. thank you for any help in advance

here is my code :

```
Sub AdataPreparation()
Dim WorkBk As Workbook, WorkSh As Worksheet, FilterRow As Variant, DurtyRows as range 

Set WorkSh = Sheets("feuil2")
WorkSh.Activate
FilterRow = Rows("1:1").Find(What:="ID", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
set DurtyRows as WorkSh.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=FilterRow, Criteria1:="=" 
DurtyRows.Delete Shift :=xlUp
End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include an "MCVE" Example.  (See: "[mcve]").  As it stands your code won't even compile and it's not clear what you're trying to do.  Sample data and some background would also be helpful. See [ask] as well as [help/on-topic].

Comment: What on earth are `set DurtyRows as` and `Deleteelete`? Hardly surprising your code doesn't work.

Comment: Also, it's `Shift:=xlUp` (it's lowercase "L") not `...x1up`

Comment: This thread may help you on your journey, it shows how to delete the filtered rows
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49774855/delete-visible-rows-after-filter-applied/49775737#49775737

Comment: Hi there. sorry for my dirty code that i posted yesterday. 
it was the end of the day with some Vision disorders. 
here is the code without delleting autofilter result ( a blank cells ).
 it works and maybe it could help some one. 
 for the deleting of the result im working on it

Comment: Sub AdataPreparation()
 
 Dim WorkSh As Worksheet, FilterRow As Variant, DurtyRows as range 
 
 Set WorkSh = Sheets("feuil2")
 
 WorkSh.Activate
 
 FilterRow = Rows("1:1").Find(What:="ID", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
 
 WorkSh.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=FilterRow, Criteria1:="=" 
 
 End Sub

Comment: @Davesexcel: thank you for sharing the link. it is thanks to that that I found the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to always use an autofilter to find the empty cells before removing them but I'm stuck with it . instead  i used SpecialCells function Since i want to delete the Empty cells. So it Works but if I want to delete other celles dipending other special criteria than blank or somting that is not specified in SpecialCells Methode , i will have a problem but So far here is a solution. i Hope that will help some one. Here is a code. If you have a solution using Autofilter please share. Thanks

```
Sub data()

 Dim Wrksh As Worksheet, DurtyRows As Range, LstRw As Long


Set WorkSh = Sheets("feuil2")

    With WorkSh
    LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set DurtyRows = .Range("A1:A" & LstRw).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    DurtyRows.EntireRow.Delete
    .AutoFilterMode = False
  End With

End Sub
```